# isPrime method for a number created by an array of ints?

Tags: java, arrays

I wanna create an isPrime method for a number that is formed from an array of ints, i.e an array of 25 ints is filled starting from the end. e.g 13512 would look like this: {0,0,0,0,0,...0,0,1,3,5,1,2}. So my goal is to create an isPrime method for a number of this form. I need some ideas for a good algorithm. Any help?

Comment: Can't you just use `BigInteger` instead of array of digits?

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following approach

```
boolean isPrime(BigInteger n) {
    //check if n is a multiple of 2
    if (n.remainder(2)==0) return false;
    //if not, then just check the odds
    for(int i=3;i*i<=n;i+=2) {
        if(n.remainder(i)==0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

   boolean processArray(int[] a)
{
    BigInteger bi = BigInteger.valueOf(0);
    for(int i=0;i<a.length();i++)
    {
        bi = bi.add(BigInteger.valueOf(a[i]*(Math.pow(10,i))));
    }
   return isPrime(bi);

}
```

Call processArray with the array you have.

Comment: You can't use % with BigInts.